# $.ajax errors will not display from php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, error-handling

I'm new to using jQuery with AJAX. I want to build a simple form that prompts the user when one of the field inputs are incorrect.

My only requirement (for now) is that the name must be "John".

html (ajaxtutorial.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>AJAX Form</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form action="ajax/contact.php" method="post" class="ajax">
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your name">
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Your email">
        </div>
        <div>
        <textarea name="message" placeholder="Your message"></textarea>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Send">
        <div>
    </form>

    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

jQuery (main.js):

```
$('form.ajax').on('submit', function() {
    var that = $(this),
        url = that.attr('action'),
        type = that.attr('method'),
        data = {};

    that.find('[name]').each(function(index, value) {
        var that = $(this), //references the inputs within the find function
            name = that.attr('name'),
            value = that.val();

            data[name] = value;
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: type,
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function(result) {
            if(result.error == true) {
                console.log('Did not type John');
            } 
            else {
                console.log('Typed John');
            }
        }
    }); 
    return false;
});
```

php (contact.php):

```
<?php

    $errors = array();
    $form_data = array();

    $name = htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']);
    $email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
    $message = htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']);

    if ($name != 'John') {
    $errors['name'] = true;
    }

    if (array_key_exists('name',$errors)) {
        $form_data['success'] = true;
        $form_data['error'] = true;
    } elseif (empty($errors)) {
        $form_data['success'] = true;
    }
    echo json_encode($form_data);
?>
```

I feel it's simple, but can't solve it. I want to identify the error by it's class (i.e. result.['class']) in order to provide unique feedback for each error.

Thanks for the help

Comment: are you sure you the data you are sending to your php script exists.  Also instead of that each loop that you are doing you can just put $(this).serialize() in you ajax request block

Comment: Have you checked your Network tab to see what response the PHP returns?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) instead of looping like,

```
$('form.ajax').on('submit', function() {
    var that = $(this),
        url = that.attr('action'),
        type = that.attr('method');  

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: type,
        data: that.serialize(),// use form.serialize() here
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function(result) {
            if(result.error == true) {
                console.log('Did not type John');
            } 
            else {
                console.log('Typed John');
            }
        }
    });        
    return false;    
});
```

Also in PHP in case of error, your are assigning `success` and `error` both try it like,

```
if (array_key_exists('name',$errors)) {
    // remove success key from here
    $form_data['error'] = true;// only error
} elseif (empty($errors)) {
    $form_data['success'] = true; // only success
}
echo json_encode($form_data);
```

Comment: Thanks for the letting me know about the serialize() shortcut!